# Error No : 150 in creating table via hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am creating table one to many mapping via hibernate but some problem occur it could not update table.

StackTrace

```
    May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Organisation.hbm.xml
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Data.hbm.xml
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/notifier]
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: notifier.data
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [org_id, id, user_name, address, date, city, mobile_no]
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: notifier.organisation
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [org_id, username, person_mobile_no, email, person_name, estimatedpeople, orgname, org_mobile_no, password, orgaddress, city]
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
May 05, 2015 8:36:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
May 05, 2015 8:36:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table DATA add index FK1FE7AA2ED256C (ORG_ID), add constraint FK1FE7AA2ED256C foreign key (ORG_ID) references ORGANISATION (ORG_ID)
May 05, 2015 8:36:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: Can't create table 'notifier.#sql-b18_c' (errno: 150)
May 05, 2015 8:36:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
```

Error is showing in 3rd last line in stacktrace

Data.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="hibernate.Data" table="DATA">

    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="" class="hibernate.Organisation">
        <column name="ORG_ID"></column>
    </many-to-one>


    <property name="orgId" column="ORG_ID" insert="true" update="false"
        length="10" />

    <property name="date" column="DATE" length="20" />
    <property name="userName" column="USER_NAME" length="20" />
    <property name="mobileNo" column="MOBILE_NO" length="20" />
    <property name="address" column="ADDRESS" length="20" />
    <property name="city" column="CITY" length="20" />


</class>
```

Organisation.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >

 <hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="hibernate.Organisation" table="ORGANISATION">

    <id name="orgId" column="ORG_ID" length="5">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="orgName" column="ORGNAME" length="25" />
    <property name="orgAddress" column="ORGADDRESS" length="500" />
    <property name="city" column="CITY" length="25" />
    <property name="orgMobileNO" column="ORG_MOBILE_NO" length="12" />
    <property name="personName" column="PERSON_NAME" length="25" />
    <property name="personMobileNo" column="PERSON_MOBILE_NO"
        length="12" />
    <property name="email" column="EMAIL" length="50" />
    <property name="estimatedPeople" column="ESTIMATEDPEOPLE"
        length="25" />

    <property name="userName" column="USERNAME" />
    <property name="password" column="PASSWORD" />


    <set name="data" table="DATA" cascade="all">
        <!-- used to specify name of foreign key should be created in child table -->
        <key column="ORG_ID" />
        <one-to-many class="hibernate.Data" />
    </set>
</class>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
     <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
     <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
     <!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools. -->
     <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">kartik</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping resource="Organisation.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="Data.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Is any thing wrong with mapping or problem with something else.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's possible that data types are not the same for `DATA.ORG_ID` and `ORGANIZATION.ORG_ID`, so check that. Also, your mappings seems to be wrong, like mapping same column as property and join column for collection, or `many-to-many` with no name...

Comment: thanks. data type were different. Problem solved

Comment: Great. I'll post it as an answer since it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that data types are not the same for `DATA.ORG_ID` and `ORGANIZATION.ORG_ID`, so check that.